# QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ProtocolUnknownError)

Tags: c++, qt, network-protocols, qnetworkaccessmanager

In my project, I am attempting to download a YouTube profile picture. The YouTube API returns this link `https://yt3.ggpht.com/-7ipuUvDjVT8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/hSPOcUsb1nw/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg`

However, using the same function for downloading files from my own website doesn't work with this URL. I get `QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ProtocolUnknownError)` in the application output.

Here is my code:

```
QByteArray downloadFileData(QString url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        return reply->readAll();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << reply->error();
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    return "";
}
```

When I pass that url to this function, I get that error. What is going on?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks for that totally unhelpful and pointless comment. The code snippet is all the is needed in this instance.

Comment: Is SSL functioning? (See QSslSocket::supportsSsl())

Comment: @peppe What happens when you call this function with that url. Does it work for you? Looking into QSslSocket now.

Comment: Ah! I built Qt from source but didn't include an ssl solution. So I rebuilt with OpenSSL and now it works great! Thanks!

Comment: I know this post is old but when you say "I rebuilt with OpenSSL and now it works". How did you actually do that...?

Comment: I apologize, but I truly don't remember. :/

Comment: No problem. I solved my problem which didn't seem to be related to SSL but to my version of Qt ;)